# Tool for lossless image compression

Tags: compression, imaging, pagespeed, image-compression

Running [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/) on a public site , I saw some suggestions by the tool like the following :

Losslessly compressing http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Acer-120x120._V137848950_.gi could save 4.8KiB (26% reduction) and they also provide a link to the  optimized content.But they do it on a per image basis. I saw some significant reduction on file sizes after compression. So the question is :

Is there any tool or web service that I can use so that I give it a directory of uncompressed images(say .gif) and it returns me a directory of images with all of them compressed?

I found a somewhat related question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451597/how-does-googles-page-speed-lossless-image-compression-work) but it is not an exact duplicate.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153122/image-compression-tools-via-command-line (I've just posted an answer over there covering png, jpeg and gif).

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac, I've had good success with [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/). It handles PNG, JPEG, and GIF files in a drap & drop manner and can also process entire directories. It's also open-source and available in multiple languages.

On Windows, I've used both [PngOptimizer](http://psydk.org/PngOptimizer) and [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/). Unlike ImageOptim, these programs will convert other formats to PNG, so if your goal is to reduce a GIF or JPEG and have it stay in that format, these won't be an option.

You could also try the Yahoo web site/service [smush.it](http://smush.it/) which can handle single file uploads as well as a directory zip.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for losslessly compressing images for the web (JPG, PNG and GIF) is [FileOptimizer](http://nikkhokkho.sourceforge.net/static.php?page=FileOptimizer). It can compress images up to 10% of its original size sometimes. A few of the better online tools are [this compressor](http://www.giftofspeed.com/png-compressor/) for PNG's and [this one](https://kraken.io/web-interface) for JPG's.

I would go with the FileOptimzer if you have a lot of images though. If you have just a few it's easier to use the online tools.

Comment: you can compress jpeg,png,gif images using this online tool http://way2enjoy.com/compress-png

Answer (score 0):

GIF, PNG and even JPEG lossless optimization is possible. Because, these formats includes enough redundancy. As to PNG format, I use [cryopng](http://encode.ru/threads/1260-CryoPNG-short-introduction) script. You can find some other compression related things at [here](http://www.encode.ru/).

Comment: I knew that optimization could be done but I am just asking for tools here .

Comment: @Subhra : That's why I've added the links :)

Comment: Those links don't help much. However, thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using lossless Jpegoptim ([GitHub](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim)) and I get the best results with this tool, very often close to Google Page Speed suggestions and sometimes even better.

I'm on Linux so if I navigate to the folder with the images I simply use this command to compress all images:

```
jpegoptim *.jpg -s
```

Or use this if you want to compress only specific image:

```
jpegoptim image.jpg -s
```

It basically strips all the markers from the output file which can sometimes reduce the image size even for 50%! The image quality stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [highcompress](http://www.highcompress.com) and this one is my favorite because the best part is quality and size. I have compared with many online tools and in most of the cases it gives best compression and best quality so now I don't go here and there and directly use this. If any other better you know kindly share