# Image Compression tools via command line

Tags: optimization, image-processing, image-compression

I'm searching best tool to compress images (png and jpeg) via command line.
After googling I found **trimage** which is good as it compresses both png and jepeg, but compression ratio is very poor in this case.

I came across **jpeg-optimizer.com** online tool which does the job way better than trimage. Can any one help to find the right tool for this.

Comment: https://images.guide/ lists many tools and dives into several image formats.

Comment: `zopflipng --iterations=500 --filters=01234mepb input.png output.png` took like an hour on a 170 KB image and resulted in a 112 KB file.

Answer (score 49):

I'm using the following tools to perform **lossless** image compression:

- [`pngcrush`](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)
- [`gifsicle`](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/)
- [`jpegtran`](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/)

For each of the programs, I've created two shortcuts:

1. One that does the actual compression, and shows the file size of both files
2. One that replaces the original file with the compressed one (If I'm satisfied, I'll do arrow-up, prefix my previous command with a "m", and press enter).

I've put this in my `.bashrc`:

```bash
# Image optimization tools
png() {
    pngcrush -brute "$1"{,.} && du -b "$1"{,.}
}
gif() {
    gifsicle -O "$1" -o "$1." && du -b "$1"{,.}
}
jpeg() {
    jpegtran "$1" > "$1." && du -b "$1"{,.}
}
# Just for easy access in history
mpng() {
    mv "$1"{.,}
}
mgif() {
    newsize=$(wc -c <"$1.")
    oldsize=$(wc -c <"$1")
    if [ $oldsize -gt $newsize ] ; then
        mv "$1"{.,}
    else
        rm "$1."
    fi  
}
mjpeg() {
    mv "$1"{.,}
}
```

Note: `pngcrush -brute` is very verbose. Redirect the output to `/dev/null` if you're not interested in the progress.

Comment: gifsicle only started optimising with the `-O3` flag in a new release (not available on `apt` currently) - see [release 1.82.1](https://github.com/pornel/giflossy/releases) (replace your `/usr/bin/gifsicle` binary the appropriate one). My notes on gif optimisation with it are [here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Gif-terminal-manipulation)

Comment: Your `jpegtran` command seems to do nothing at all, it results in a file of the exact same size. Why do you have no options specified?

Comment: @jphollowed `jpegtran` optimizes by default. If the file does not change, then jpegtran cannot reduce the size in a lossless way.

Comment: I like pngcrush because of lossless compression. I just copy the png files to a temp diretory. Then I run a batch file in Windows that processes all the PNG in the current directory. `for /R %cd% %%f in (*.png) do (
  pngcrush -reduce -brute -ow "%%~nf.png" "temp%%~nf.png" )`  Then I run a folder comparison program to review the two folders and visually files are identical but I copy over the smaller optimized files to the source directory.

Answer (score 40):

- Lossy PNG: [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) and [rdopng](https://github.com/richgel999/rdopng)
- Lossless PNG: [oxipng](https://github.com/shssoichiro/oxipng), [AdvPNG](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/doc-advpng.html) (good and fast) or [ZopfliPNG](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/compress-data-more-densely-with-zopfli.html) (slow, but best)
- Lossless JPG: [mozjpeg's jpegtran](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) or [deprecated jpegrescan](https://github.com/kud/jpegrescan)
- Lossy JPG: [mozjpeg's cjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) ([try online](https://imageoptim.com/mozjpeg)) or [imgmin](https://github.com/rflynn/imgmin)
- If you're running macOS: [ImageOptim CLI](https://github.com/JamieMason/ImageOptim-CLI)

Comment: For ease of use `advpng -4` will use the zopfli compression algorithm.

Answer (score 17):

If you are on Linux, try [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) tool from the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite

It is quite handy on command line.

Ex :

`mogrify -resize 50% rose.jpg`

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

Comment: Or try the faster fork: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/